# Rails controller - random record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Simple question, will this code ensure that the rand() call doesn't return the same record twice in a row?

It seems to, from click tests, but I really don't feel confident.

```
def thoughts  
  last_thought = 0 if last_thought == nil #this is the part that seems wrong for my goal
  th = Array.new

  Thought.all.each do |t|
    th << t.id
  end

  th.pop(last_thought)
  @rand_thought = Thought.find(rand(th.first..th.last))
  last_thought = @rand_thought.id
end
```

---

Based upon @user198201's suggestions, I've revised the code to this:

```
def thoughts
  shuffle_thought ||= Thought.all.shuffle
  @rand_thought = shuffle_thought.pop
  @rand_thought
end
```

Then to test, I added this method:

```
def thinker
  a = Array.new
  20.times do
    a << thoughts.id
  end
  a
end
```

Here's what I get now in the Rails Console:

t = ThoughtController.new

=> #<'ThoughtController:0x007f95636ae000>

t.thought.id

```
Thought Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
```

=> 7

t.thinker

```
Thought Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
Thought Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "thoughts".* FROM "thoughts"
```

=> [5, 9, 4, 7, 4, 5, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 1, 8, 6, 4, 1, 2, 7, 3, 2]

And right there in the middle of the array is a repeat. I'm still looking for code to keep from getting the same record twice in a row.

Comment: when will last_thought not be nil?

Comment: "doesn't return the same record twice" -- does this mean in 2 successive requests, or when this method is called twice within the same request? In either case, it very well **could** return the same record twice in a row.

Comment: Vimsha I set last_thought to @rand_thought.id at the end of the block. AlexD, 2 successive requests. When the webpage is reloaded, it returns a different thought.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're loading all of the thoughts, it's not clear why you're returning to the database to fetch your random thought.

```
def random_thought
  @thoughts ||= Thought.all.shuffle
  @thoughts.pop
end
```

Note that the @thoughts stores all the thoughts into an instance variable that should still be there next time you call random_thought, within the current request anyway, whereas random_thoughts ||= won't work because it stores the thoughts in a local variable. This means that it disappears every time you ask for a random thought, which causes all the thoughts to be loaded every time, which your log output suggests, thereby increasing the chances that you'll get a repeat, as well as being woefully inefficient. If all the thoughts are stored in @thoughts and shuffled, you're guaranteed never to run until you've popped off all the @thoughts.

Alex D is correct re: efficiency. For the purpose of your experiment it is okay to load all the thoughts; if this were a production site it would be a disaster. For some ideas look at the SQL Antipatterns book, summarized in a slideshare here: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back

Skip ahead to slide 148. You essentially want to query for the max ID, select an ID based on a random number, and grab the next highest existing record.

Comment: This is better than the OP's code, in that if he calls it twice in the same request, it will not "return the same record twice". It still pulls the entire `thoughts` table into memory, which will cause problems if the table is even moderately large.

Comment: This code is much cleaner and I appreciate the .shuffle method. However, it doesn't answer my original question. I've added to my question above.